# background-color semi transparente sobre un <img>

Tags: html, css, html5

Tengo un tag `<img>`con un tamaño definido, no importa el tamaño de la imagen que se le cargue, ahora necesito agregarle una capa de color semitransparente sobre este `<img>`
le cargo de la siguiente manera, pero el color no se sobrepone en la imagen, alguna idea de como pueda agregarle un color de fondo?

HTML

```
<div class="imgCat" style=" ">
   <img src="imagen.jpg" style="height: 200px; width: 293px; background-color:rgba(102,255,255,0.5)">
   <div class="row categorias-experience">
       <div class="nombre-categoria centered">Gourmet</div>
   </div>                           
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

podrias poner un fondo al div que contiene la imagen y utilizar el atributo css:  `opacity` en la foto

ejemplo :

```css
img{
  height: 200px;
  width: 293px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.contenedor-img{
  background: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 293px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgCat" style=" ">
  <div class="contenedor-img">
    <img src="https://www.pcactual.com/medio/2018/09/16/imagen-a-jpg_6929b44b.jpg" >
  </div>
    <div class="row categorias-experience">
      <div class="nombre-categoria centered">Gourmet</div>
    </div>                           
</div>
```

el `opacity` funciona como el canal Alfa del `RGBA` osea va de 0 a 1, espero te sea de ayuda, exitos

Comment: Gracias me funciono!

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente lo puedes hacer con la pseudoclase de css ::before que le añade una capa con propiedades aparte de la principal. Existe tambien ::after, par ejecutar el ejemplo aqui en stackoverflow, tem paciencia que la imagen se demora en cargar, puede tambien copiar el codigo html y css en un archivo local y se ejecutara mas rapido.

```css
 .superimagen {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
color: white;
font-size: 30px;
background:#00ff4866;
}
.superimagen:before {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
content: " ";
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200");
background-size: 100% 100%;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="superimagen"></div>
```